# ¿Cómo redireccionar a una pagina con un botón en HTML?

Tags: html

Acá les dejo el código que estoy usando.
Intente varias formas pero no pude.

```
    <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrarse">
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta esto:

```html
<a href="/ponAquiLaPagina">
   <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrarse">
</a>
```

Comment: Eso está mal, no debes de hacer eso

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#properties

Answer (score 1):

he podido encontrar la solución, la comparto por si a alguien le sirve.

```
    <input class="botons" type="submit" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'" value="Registrarse">
```

Answer (score 0):

El truco está en que no es un botton, es un anchor tag

```css
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4E9CAF;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Con esos estilos parecerá botón

`< a class="button">Add Problem</a>`